# I am trying to get the virtual xp to use the same dafault gateway as the mac

Tags: macos, networking, vmware-fusion, gateway

I have a wireless printer HP 8500 officejet pro and the default gateway changed on the mac but not in the xp so I can't install the software for the wireless printer. How can I make my mac and the xp use the same default gateway address?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to help without knowing more about your infrastructure or the changes made.

For the virtual XP, simply go to command prompt and type `IPCONFIG /RENEW`, if the DHCP settings changed it should now get the correct ones.

I would say how to do manually, but I am guessing that if you ever set it, you would know how to change it.

If this doesn't solve it, please say in comments what is wrong and I will try to help you further.